# average of dBs or dB of average?

Tags: gain, decibel

In several papers, books etc. I have encountered to expression of "average gain of the path is ... dB", now I wonder this is the average of dBs or dB of averages? The sources have not mentioned anything about their usage. Which one is used as a common definition?

Comment: The average of dB's is the geometric mean, while the dB of averages is an arithmetic mean. I don't see why they would want a geometric mean, but maybe there's a reason. What papers/books are you looking at?

Comment: @helloworld922 It is so weird, since if you said for average of dBs we use arithmetic and for dB of averages we use geometric it had an explanation (till both of them be equal to each other), but for this case that is completely vice versa, we must see .  The place that I have seen it is for example Matlab. When it accepts the average path power in dB to define the channel coefficients, I wonder which definition is used there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, when taken an average of numbers expressed in dB, you should convert each one to its corresponding ratio, average the ratios, and then convert back to dB.  Otherwise, as already pointed out, you would be calculating the geometric and not the arithmetic mean.  In practice, however, if the values in dB are not far apart, say a few dB, then the average of the dB's will be very close to the dB of the average.  Thus you can usually skip the conversion step.  For example, if the values are 9, 10, and 11 dB, then the difference in the two procedures is only about 0.03 dB.

Comment: That is not necessarily true - things measured in dB are quite often things where the "benefit" of a number is logarithmic, classically human hearing.  However, sometimes they are also things where the "cost" is more linear, so for example if you were looking at waste heat, you might want the linear time average (but then you probably also would be expressing the result in linear units).  In the end it depends on why you want an average, but the decision to express your values in a log or linear scale is often not unrelated.

Comment: I agree with @Chris, it is context dependant, and i think Barry gives really dangerous advice, particularly for ppl not so experienced working in dB... suggesting the use of incorrect calculations based on the values being "close enough".  the conversion takes seconds... so just calculate it correctly

Answer (score 1):

If I saw the expression "The average gain of the path is 10 dB", I would assume that the gain varies around 10 dB - if I take a number of measurements at different times, I might see 10 dB, 12 dB, 8 dB, 9 dB, 11 dB...., with the average of those measurements being 10 dB.

I don't know what a "dB of averages" would mean.

Comment: by "dB of averages" I mean, in your example which the average gain is 10 dB, it is 10 Watt, so the gain varies around 10 Watt, and we have obtained first the average of gains in Watt, then we have transform it into dB. They will yield completely different answers

Comment: Where have you seen the term 'dB of averages'?

Comment: @AMIR 10dB is not necessarily 10W. dB is just a ratio - specifically either \$20\log_{10}(a/b)\$ (for voltage gain) or \$10\log_{10}(a/b)\$ (for voltage gain). Now 40dBm would be 10W, because dBm is decibels referenced to 1mW.

Comment: @Chu I have not seen it anywhere, as I have not seen average of dBs as well. They have used only the term the average gain in dB is ... , or for example this function accepts its first argument as the average path power in dB

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RTbecard. Since it is easy enough to take the average correctly, just do it correctly. "Correctly" means: [1] "Un-dB" the dB values making them "linear values." [2] Take the average (arithmetic mean) of the linear values. [3] Calculate the dB version of the average.  If you have X dB, then the linear version of that number is X_lin = 10^(X/10).  In less than the amount of time it takes to determine if the wrong approach yields a result that is "close enough," you can instead just do it the right way and always be exact.  This issue came up at work today.  The correct method that I was using gave a much different result from the incorrect method a colleague had used.